# Nginx Redirect All Non-www Traffic to www on Ports 80 and 443

Tags: http, nginx, https, ssl-certificate

My Nginx server block is currently configured to serve both non-www and www traffic. How can I configure my server block to:

http://example.com should go to: https://www.example.com

https://example.com should go to: https://www.example.com

Here is what I currently have:

```
server {
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Does your certificate includes both `example.com` and `www.example.com` domain names?

Comment: Yes, it does. Both work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your SSL server block by two:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Leave the server block that listen on port 80 as is.

Comment: I entered nginx -t and got:
nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for [::]:443 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:14
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: @GTSJoe According to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/638367/do-you-need-separate-ipv4-and-ipv6-listen-directives-in-nginx/685266#685266) answer and comments below you shoudn't use `ipv6only=on`, just `listen 443 ssl; listen [::]:443 ssl;`.

Comment: @GTSJoe And [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/896543/nginx-certbot-certificate-www-and-non-www/896555#896555) is a few notes about certbot from [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton). I agreed with him about certbot and an ugly configuration it usually produce.

Comment: Great! It's working now after removing ipv6only=on. Thank you for the answer and links to sources. 